# Representing (32-n) with bit manipulation without "-" sign in C

Tags: c

So I am currently working on a project involving bit manipulation for class and one of the stipulations is that we cannot use the "-" sign for anything (for example instead of writing -1 I have to write ~0)

I want to do a right shift n-bits, but I can't do something like 5 >> (32 - n) because of the "-" sign and I am stumped on how to do it otherwise.

Can someone enlighten me please?

Comment: Can't you use `5 >> n`?

Comment: I suppose I could in that case actually, but I am dealing with a case of x >> (32-n)

Comment: @owacoder  He cant use `-` but that expression doesn't have that either . he can technically use that .

Comment: add a huge value to it and and force a overflow?

Answer (score 3):

In the comments you said the real use case was:

```
x >> (32 - n)
```

You're allow to use bit invert (e.g. `~0` instead of `-1`), so just do either:

```
x >> (32+(n * ~0)) // Straightforward negate of n using substitute for -1
```

or

```
x >> (33 + ~n)  // Direct use of two's complement to get -n, since -n == (~n) + 1
```

Comment: ~n is not that basically -(n+1)

Comment: @GRC: I don't understand what you're trying to say... If you're wondering about the final example, I included the `+ 1` in the constant, `33 + ~n` being the same as `32 + (~n + 1)`.

Comment: You are right, I was answring this question right before I went to bed. :)

Answer (score 2):

Okay this is a bit gross and not efficient, but I'm assuming this is more of a theoretical experiment rather a something anyone would do.

You can represent -1 by using ~0  (This inverts all the bits of 0 so that that all bits are set. This is -1 on regular processors).
So if you wanted -n you could go n*(~0)

```
5 >> (32 + ((~0) * n))
```

Answer (score 1):

A right shift of n-bits would use the ">>" operator.

```
5 >> n;
```

The example you gave of 5 << (32-n) is a left shift. The 32-n does not make a left shift into a right shift.

Comment: Yeah, I realized I mistyped my question. I am actually dealing with the case (5 >> (32-n)) and my code breaks when I do 5 << n

Comment: 32 - n == 32 + ~n + 1

Comment: @rcgldr Okay, that actually works, now I just gotta figure out why it works.

Comment: @user3483844 - to negate a number, take the ones complement and add 1.

Comment: @user3483844  Its calles 2's complement. It a way to represent negative numbers in binary.

Comment: Technically that is not portable. 2's complement is not guaranteed.

Comment: Well, he's been given that `~0` is a legal replacement for `-1`, so clearly the assignment assumes two's complement.

Comment: That is true, although I was not pointing that out only for the OP. Future viewers may wonder...

Comment: @owacoder yeah, we are using 2's compliment and it's assumed that we are on a 32 bit machine